# rails if object.nil? then magic '' in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is one of those things, that maybe so simple I'll never find it because everyone else already knows it.

I've got objects I have to check for nil in my views so I don't dereference a nil:

```
<%= if tax_payment.user; tax_payment.user.name; end %>
```

Or I could do this variant:

```
<%= tax_payment.user ? tax_payment.user.name : '' %>
```

So this is ok ... for most languages. But I feel like there must be some bit of shiny ruby or railness I'm still missing if this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What about:

```
<%= tax_payment.user.name if tax_payment.user %>
```

Answer (score 46):

You can also try the new Object.try syntax, pardon the pun.

This is in the shiny new Rails 2.3:

```
tax_payment.try(:user).try(:name)
```

Comment: Cool that is also like what I was looking for, I look forward to that release.

Answer (score 10):

The Ruby community has put an incredible amount of attention to automating this idiom. These are the solutions I know of:

- [try](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-object-try) in Ruby on Rails
- Another [try](http://ruby.tie-rack.org/53/a-better-try-chaining-methods-and-nil/)
- [andand](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/01/objectandand-objectme-in-ruby.html)
- A safer [andand](http://github.com/raganwald/rewrite_rails/tree/master)
- [Kernel::ergo](http://facets.rubyforge.org/quick/rdoc/core/classes/Kernel.html#M000368)
- [send-with-default](http://rhnh.net/2007/10/02/object-send-with-default)
- [maybe](http://weavejester.com/node/10)
- [_?](http://hobocentral.net/blog/2007/08/25/quiz/)
- [if-not-nil](http://recursive.ca/hutch/2007/11/22/a-little-unnecessary-smalltalk-envy/)
- [turtles!](http://chalain.livejournal.com/66798.html)
- [method_](http://www.urubatan.info/2008/03/a-better-try-for-ruby-why-not-do-the-groovy-way/) in Groovy style
- [do-or-do-not](http://www.bencurtis.com/archives/2008/03/do-or-do-not/)

The most well-known is probably the [try method](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-object-try) in Rails. However, it has received [some](http://blog.lawrencepit.com/2009/01/11/try-as-you-might/) [criticism](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2008-12-16/welcome.md).

In any case, I think Ben's solution is perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

I've always preferred this approach:

model:

```
class TaxPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, :to=>:user, :prefix=>true, :allow_nil=>true
end
```

view:

```
<%= tax_payment.user_name %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 7):

For a little more comprehensive solution, you could check out the [*Introduce Null Object* Refactoring](http://Refactoring.Com/catalog/introduceNullObject.html). The basic mechanics of this refactoring is that instead of checking for `nil` in the *client* code you instead make sure that the *provider* never produces a `nil` in the first place, by introducing a context-specific *null object* and returning that.

So, return an empty string, an empty array, an empty hash or a special empty customer or empty user or something instead of just `nil` and then you will never need to check for `nil` in the first place.

So, in your case you would have something like

```
class NullUser < User
    def name
        return ''
    end
end
```

However, in Ruby there is actually another, quite elegant, way of implementing the Introduce Null Object Refactoring: you don't actually need to *introduce* a Null Object, because `nil` is *already* an object! So, you could monkey-patch `nil` to behave as a NullUser – however, all the usual warnings and pitfalls regarding monkey-patching apply even more strongly in this case, since making `nil` silently swallow `NoMethodError`s or something like that can totally mess up your debugging experience and make it *really* hard to track down cases where there is a `nil` that shouldn't be there (as opposed to a `nil` that serves as a Null Object).

Answer (score 2):

I just do

```
<%= tax_payment.user.name rescue '' %>
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted, is it bad practice? Seems perfectly elegant to me.

Comment: I'm upvoting just on principle that if no one has explained it in all these years, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which makes sense occasionally...

If tax_payment.user returns nil, nil.to_s (an empty string) is printed, which is harmless. If there is a user, it will print the user's name.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper method which looks like this:

```
def print_if_present(var)
    var ? var : ""
end
```

And then use it like this (in the view):

`<%= print_if_present(your_var) %>`

If the var is nil, it just prints nothing without raising an exception.