# Confused about nil rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, null

I'm simply trying to ensure a value exists in a certain block and to display it's contents if it does and if not display "Nothing for this yet." I've researched [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749157/checking-for-nil-in-view-in-ruby-on-rails) [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523164/rails-if-object-nil-then-magic-in-views) but my implementation must be off.

```
<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <%= profile.current_club %>
  <% if profile.listings %>
    <%= video_thumb_embed(profile.listings.last.video).html_safe %>
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

- Video is an attribute of the listings model.
- I'm trying to display all user profiles on an index page and to display the latest video they have added on this index page.
- It errors out if a user hasn't added a listing so I added what I thought would be a simple check in the each block but it errors out with the below

  undefined method `video' for nil:NilClass

What am I not understanding here? With the above I expect a profile would show on the index page with a video if it had one and if it didn't it wouldn't display anything.

Comment: Your error indicates that `profile.listings.last` is nil. Try outputting `profile.listings` to make sure that you have an array of listings.

Comment: I can confirm outputting `profile.listings` would give `[]`. Ok, so if a user hasn't added a listing yet the array will be empty. Does this mean I would just check if the array has any elements and my check would work as expected?

Comment: yes, you just have to change `if profile.listings` to `if !profile.listings.blank?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check and make sure that profile.listings is not blank or empty. If you call the `last` method on an empty array, it returns nil.

`<% if profile.listings %>` will return `true` even if you have an empty array.

`<% if !profile.listings.blank? %>` or `<% unless profile.listings.blank? %>` should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect, I went with `.empty?` just for my own readability purposes. Thanks for talking it out. Everything working.