# Replace Nil Values before_save Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, model

I have a json file that I'm importing into my Rails DB.

JSON:

```
{
 "data": [{
   "title": "foo",
   "color": "bar",
   "size" : "baz",
   "occupation" : "engineer",
   "location" : "dallas",
   "car" : "tesla",
   "married" : true,
   "dogs" : 4,
   "food" : "tacos"   
}]
```

Now lets say "title" is not listed in one of the samples and it's stored as nil. I know I can update this with before_save in the model

```
Class Person
  before_save :replace_nil_values

  private

  def replace_nil_values
    self.title = "Not Listed" if title == nil
  end
end
```

This works. The problem is what happens if multiple properties are missing or listed as nil? I feel doing this would be super inefficient:

```
def replace_nil_values
  self.title = "Not Listed" if title == nil
  self.color= "Not Listed" if color == nil
  self.size = "Not Listed" if size == nil
  self.occupation = "Not Listed" if occupation == nil
  self.location = "Not Listed" if location == nil
  self.car = "Not Listed" if car == nil
end
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to leave them as `nil` in the database. If you need to display "Not Listed" in your UI, then do that when you display the data.  This provides a number of benefits:

- You can easily change "Not Listed" to something else down the road.
- You can translate it on the fly.
- You won't ever confuse a blank "Not Listed" with a legitimate "Not Listed" entered by the user.

Comment: Thanks Philip! I never considered those consequences. I ran with your answer and implemented a helper method explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22098115/3007294
Appreciate it!

Comment:  You may want to read about decorator/presenter patterns which would allow you to create say a `PersonPresenter` with a `title` method that would encapsulate your helper logic. Same thing, just consolidates it some. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper for another option.